# can git metadata be read over http without cloning

Tags: git, http

Attempting to load `https://domain/path/project.git/HEAD` gives me a 404 on both bitbucket and github, and according to the git book (git-scm.com), this should not be the case.

Are these two sites a special case or am I doing something wrong?

*Please note that I want to avoid downloading the entire repository if possible.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by git metadata?

Comment: Mainly the hash for the tip master branch and last commit time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do assumes the old Git HTTP protocol, which simply used static files. Github and Bitbucket use Git's newer HTTP protocol, with an active (programmed) server, so there's no URL named "HEAD".

Therefore, you need to at least communicate with it using a smart client. That's not necessarily to say that you need to clone the repository, however; there may well be tools to talk with the server without having to do a full clone. For example, there's `git ls-remote`:

```
$ git ls-remote http://server/git/project
7f38468acf1de9b73d931aebf9a8add8f691a6dc        HEAD
7f38468acf1de9b73d931aebf9a8add8f691a6dc        refs/heads/master
```

For further information, see the manpage for `git-http-backend`.

(Also, it should be noted that if all you want to avoid is "downloading the *entire* repository", then you could simply do a shallow clone.)

Comment: git ls-remote can only give you the hash of each ref. It cannot directly give you the content.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/).  Simply call a GET with basic auth (if needed) to `/repos/:owner/:repo/commits` and parse the JSON response

I understand your question was regarding HTTP...this is just an alternative. I don't believe it's possible otherwise.